# How to proccessing array in array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Can someone help me with this difficult array 
In the web im find all cities and regions of Ukraine and im want to display this in select-option tag 
I want to show separately regions and cities
This is [link](https://api.hh.ru/areas/5) of json file

Also im saved this JSON file on my PC
This is my code of proccessing arrays

```
public function index()
{

    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents('5.json'));
    foreach ($result as $k => $v)
    {
       foreach ($v as $item)
       {
           dd($item);
       }
    }
    return response()->json($item);
}
```

Comment: Have You tried Array Helpers?

Comment: Sorry what?
I'm just a beginner at this

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel provides a fluent wrapper for arrays. See [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections).

Initialize a collection by:

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('5.json'));
$collection = collect($result);
```

Looking at your data, I don't know if this will perform well. I had experiences before where performance starts to become a problem, so please be wary of usage.

Answer (score 2):

I think should format $result to array
$result = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);

Comment: More appropriate answer, second parameter **_true_** will help you process your arrays more easily.